# Convert vb.net to asp Classic

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following VB Code:

```
 Dim value As Date = Date.Now
    Dim intHour As Integer
    Dim intMinute As Integer
    Dim intSecond As Integer


    intHour = 17
    intMinute = 0
    intSecond = 0

    Dim newdatetime As DateTime = New Date(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, intHour, intMinute, intSecond)

    If DateTime.Now < newdatetime Then

        If value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
            value = value.AddDays(2)
            Return value
        End If

        If value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
            value = value.AddDays(1)
            Return value
        End If

        Return value

    ElseIf DateTime.Now > newdatetime Then
        Do
            value = value.AddDays(1)
        Loop While (value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday) Or (value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        Return value
    End If
```

How would that be in ASP CLassic?

Can someone help ?

EDIT:

```
    Dim CurrentDate
CurrentDate = Date()

Dim intHour
Dim intMinute
Dim intSecond

intHour = 17
intMinute = 0
intSecond = 0

Dim NewDate
Dim NewDate1
Dim NewDate2

NewDate = DatePart("yyyy", CurrentDate)
NewDate1 = DatePart("m", CurrentDate)
NewDate2 = DatePart("d", CurrentDate)


Dim Dates 

Dates = DateSerial(NewDate, NewDate1, NewDate2)

Dim Time 

Time = TimeSerial(intHour, intMonth, intSecond)
```

Comment: My Problem is that i have no idea how to work with date and time in ASP Classic.

Comment: This this here: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp

Comment: I have done something. How can i put "Dates" and Time" togheter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Year: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhzx965c%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Month: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eeeket2%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Day of month: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyhfe92k%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Date comparison: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhtyw595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Day of week: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t51x9wtx%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Incrementing date: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb7z8yf9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt%28v=VS.85%29.aspx is a fantastic reference for VBScript/ASP classic.

Comment: Thanks, can you have a look at my Question. I wrotte something. But now i dont know how to put "Dates" and "Time" together. Like i have done in VB. I found nothing to do that